# Can I hardcode the "Continue After Failure" checkbox on a coded ui ordered test?

Tags: coded-ui-tests, ordered-test

Our testing team keeps getting tripped up by the "Continue after failure" checkbox getting unchecked and then the ordered test checked-in, causing our nightly run to get hosed. Is there a way to disable the checkbox and hard-code it to the checked state so that it's always checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around the problem by adding the 'continueafterfailure' attribute to the XML for the ordered tests at the start of each build. This way the checkbox functions as it normally would, but you cannot build without causing the box to become checked.